# is it okay to skip 'npm install' command from 'pre-build' section of aws codebuild buildspec.yml file

Tags: aws-lambda, yaml, continuous-deployment, aws-codebuild

i have a lambda function which is deployed via aws codebuild.

my current yml config looks like this

```
version: 0.1
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - FUNCTION_NAME=$FUNCTION_NAME
    - ZIP_NAME=$ZIP_NAME
    - BUCKET_NAME=$BUCKET_NAME
    - npm install --silent --no-progress
    - zip -r $ZIP_NAME.zip .
    - aws s3 cp $ZIP_NAME.zip s3://$BUCKET_NAME/
  build:
    commands:
    - echo $FUNCTION_NAME Deployment started!!!
    - aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $FUNCTION_NAME --s3-bucket $BUCKET_NAME --s3-key $ZIP_NAME.zip

artifacts:
  files: $ZIP_NAME.zip
```

while deploying there is a build error due to my files exceeded the maximum size limit

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the UpdateFunctionCode operation: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes
```

so there any way to fix this without removing anything from my actual code

is it okay to remove 'npm install' from the pre-build section and add to the build section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [AWS Lambda limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

- unzipped limits is 250 MB, compressed 50MB

one of workaround to shift your lambda to docker based , as lambda accept up to 10GB docker image but you will need to build docker image initially which will increase CI/CD management and cost of builds + ECR storage .

- Also lambda will need IAM permission for ECR pull.